# How do I extract this value with x-path?

Tags: php, dom, xpath, domdocument

**Source HTML**

```
  <div class="number value">14,818</div>
              <div class="number delta-negative">
                     -10.19%</div>
    <div class="number value">58,016</div>
              <div class="number delta-positive">          
                    +44.38%</div>
     <div class="number value">119,561</div>
              <div class="number delta-negative">           
                    -11232</div>
```

**Code**

```
$doc = new DomDocument(); 
$doc->loadHTMLFile('http://example.com/source.html/');
$xpath = new DomXpath($doc);  
$query = '//div[@class="number value"]//'; 
$nodes = $xpath->query($query);  
$urls = array();  
foreach ($nodes as $node) { 
$href = trim($node->nodeValue);
$urls[] = $href;}
$datap = implode(',', $urls); 
echo $datap;
```

I want extract values **14,818**, **58,016** and **119,561** but above code doesnt work...why?

Comment: Basic debugging first. Does the HTML file actually get loaded? Can you see the HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>Your query is for `class="number_value"` while your HTML says `class="number value"`.</s>

Change one of them (probably the HTML) to reflect this. (Question edited to correct error.)

---

Edit:

Running your query results in an invalid query error.  Looking at your query, it's obvious why -- you have two trailing slashes. These are invalid without anything following them.

Try this:

```
$query = '//div[@class="number value"]';
```

Comment: sorry that was a mistake actually I was testing like that I removed it. i have tried both option

Comment: @Alejandro In the original version of the question, since edited. I have altered my answer to match.